# Can't end a flight when using MechJeb

Tags: kerbal-space-program

So after it was suggested in chat, I decided to download and try the [Mechanical Jeb](http://kerbalspaceprogram.com/forum/showthread.php/12384-PLUGIN-PART-0-16-Anatid-Robotics-MuMech-MechJeb-Autopilot-v1-9) plugin.  During my trials so far with MechJeb, I've been setting up my staging such that the MechJeb module is discarded prior to re-entry.  A strange thing happens when I disconnect this stage: it disappears.  After that, everything seems normal, right through splash-down, until I try to end the flight.  The confirmation dialog appears, but after that, it doesn't show the flight log, and it's as if I hit Resume Flight instead.  I can't access anything other than the settings, and have to close KSP by way of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.  This of course means that the progress might not be saved, and when I re-open KSP, that mission can still be selected from the telemetry station.

Until I installed MechJeb, this never happened.  Can I prevent this from happening by always keeping the MechJeb unit attached?  Also, does having it active during the final staging have an effect?

Answer (score 2):

I remember having this problem with older versions of KSP (around .16 or so?). Are you using the latest versions of KSP and mechjeb?

If both are up-to-date, I'd try installing KSP to a new directory (keep the original if you'd like). Reinstall mechjeb and try again. I've had a few cases where this has fixed odd issues.

Comment: I haven't encountered this problem since I [started bringing back the MechJeb module](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/85331/1351). The last time I updated I basically did a fresh install and copied over my save files, so maybe that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure any sort of auto-pilot is disengaged. Sometimes that doesn't let you end the flight.